# "Еси" для третьего лица

Tags: славянизмы, устаревшие-слова

Речь о устаревшем "быть". "Ты еси". А он?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Он - **есть**. В грамматике Ломоносова приведены и формы для прочих лиц и мн. числа (*есмь, еси, есмы, есте, суть*) с указаниями на тогдашние ограничения в употреблении:

http://www.ruthenia.ru/apr/textes/lomonos/lomon01/359-364.htm